# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError for FragmentActivity class when running Robotium

Tags: android, intellij-idea, robotium, android-fragmentactivity, android-testing

I've tried everything I could think of, but still I cannot run my tests using Robotium.

I set the robotium library and my main project to be exported in the Project configuration as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12424392/robotium-problems-with-importing-android-robotium-project-from-eclipse-into-int)

I've set the `android:debuggable` flag to `true` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12278318/could-not-find-class-com-jayway-android-robotium-solo-solo-in-android)

I also checked the `android:targetPackage` is set properly in the manifest as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9677250/robotium-test-cannot-find-activity-class)

Also tried to change the scope of the main project dependency when building the test module to `Provided` instead of `Compile` (I am not sure what that does...)

Here is the AndroidManifest for the Test project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- package name must be unique so suffix with "tests" so package loader doesn't ignore us -->
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.matthieu.tests"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4"
              android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
            android:debuggable="true">
        <uses-library android:name="android.test.runner"/>
    </application>

    <instrumentation android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
                     android:targetPackage="com.matthieu"
                     android:label="Tests for com.matthieu"/>
</manifest>
```

And here is the exception I get:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception during suite construction
at android.test.suitebuilder.TestSuiteBuilder$FailedToCreateTests.testSuiteConstructionFailed(TestSuiteBuilder.java:239)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:169)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:154)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:520)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1447)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at com.matthieu.MainMenuActivityTest.<init>(MainMenuActivityTest.java:26)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
at android.test.suitebuilder.TestMethod.instantiateTest(TestMethod.java:87)
at android.test.suitebuilder.TestMethod.createTest(TestMethod.java:73)
at android.test.suitebuilder.TestSuiteBuilder.addTest(TestSuiteBuilder.java:263)
at android.test.suitebuilder.TestSuiteBuilder.build(TestSuiteBuilder.java:185)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onCreate(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:373)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4218)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3000(ActivityThread.java:125)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2071)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.matthieu.MainMenuActivity
... 19 more
```

Note also that I see a few errors like this in the logcat:

```
01-04 14:44:51.822: WARN/dalvikvm(1263): Class resolved by unexpected DEX: Lcom/matthieu/MainMenuActivity;(0x44e7f980):0x249f70 ref [Lcom/actionbarsherlock/app/SherlockFragmentActivity;] Lcom/actionbarsherlock/app/SherlockFragmentActivity;(0x44e7f980):0x121770
01-04 14:44:51.833: WARN/dalvikvm(1263): (Lcom/matthieu/MainMenuActivity; had used a different Lcom/actionbarsherlock/app/SherlockFragmentActivity; during pre-verification)
01-04 14:44:51.851: WARN/dalvikvm(1263): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/matthieu/MainMenuActivity; (644)
01-04 14:44:51.851: WARN/dalvikvm(1263): Link of class 'Lcom/matthieu/MainMenuActivity;' failed
01-04 14:44:51.851: ERROR/dalvikvm(1263): Could not find class 'com.matthieu.MainMenuActivity', referenced from method com.matthieu.MainMenuActivityTest.testFirstTimeAppOpening
01-04 14:44:51.851: WARN/dalvikvm(1263): VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 849 (Lcom/matthieu/MainMenuActivity;) in Lcom/matthieu/MainMenuActivityTest;
```

If it makes any difference, I am using IntelliJ Idea (11.1.5), SDK 17, SDK Tools 21.0.1 and updated Robotium to 3.6

**UPDATE**:

Found one related discussion [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/sotIalKQTUQ/discussion). I can see different error messages whether I run only one test or all the tests, and my application does use FragmentActivity. But no matter what I do, I am not able to run any test (not one, not all)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally.... I found the only way I could find to make it work [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6501955/347565)

Do not keep the Robotium test cases in a separate module... no idea why there is no way to make it work, but really I tried everything I could think of or I could find around.

Answer (score 3):

This type of errors occured when you did the below things.

1.If you entered wrong package name for "android:targetPackage" in manifest file.
so please check the target package name in the manifest file.

2.If you add the same library for  both android app and test project.

Ambiguity occurs when you add same library for  both android app and test project.so please add the library to app project only.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem for a while and tried many things, what worked for me in the end was simply going into

> properties -> Java build path -> Projects

for the test project and then removing the project under test and adding it again. (Since i cannot reproduce the problem and don't remember the details, it may be safest to remove the project under test, then clean both project, and then add the project under test)

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem again (see my other answer on this page) but could not solve the problem with my own solution this time. This time i found another solution: Removing the private libraries for the test project by right clicking on the test project and then

> properties -> Java build path -> Libraries

and removing "Android Private Libraries"

PS My answer was inspired by information i found on this page: http://android.foxykeep.com/dev/how-to-fix-the-classdefnotfounderror-with-adt-17

Answer (score 0):

I face same problem. its happen just because of i was trying to test my project with the `JUnit` instead of Android `JUnit test`.

so for that make test ***project right click on it > run as > Android Junit test***.
 it has work in my case.

best of luck